# Why Stripe is not affected by nextjs cors?

Tags: next.js, cors

I have app in nextjs 13 with app routes and I use stripe there to implement some payments, for that I use app/api/webhook/route.ts, so a simple route with a post method that will be executed when stripe call the webhook after client purchase. Nothing rare there, but my question is that I also create endpoint on app/api/newsletter/route.ts also with an post method, but now when I try to call that endpoint from another app lets a blog, I get cors issues. Why with stripe there wasnt any cors issues ?

I think both should have cors issues or nither of them

Comment: CORS only impacts user-interactive web-browsers - not headless agents like Stripe's services. CORS exists to protect users, not computers.

Answer (score 1):

Because CORS is a browser mechanism.

In your case, the former one requests from the server side to a server side, the letter one make a request from a browser to your server.

Comment: so if I make the request server side to a server side like from nextjs server, it will work ?

Comment: Yes, it will. Thanks

Comment: Thank you so much I just test it and work

Comment: @Cesar Martin Great, please accept this post as an answer.